# Raspberry Pi 4 NAS power supply requirements

Tags: pi-4, server

I'm working on a Raspberry Pi 4 NAS server and I found a power supply (5v 3A) on aliexpress:

https://s.click.aliexpress.com/e/NedqZhCc

Is the power supply going to be capable of supplying my NAS server, if not, what should I be looking for?

Comment: Buy the official power supply https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/type-c-power-supply/

Comment: save yourself future hassle and get a 10+A powered hub for peripherals in addition to a supply for the pi.

Answer (score 0):

*Your cheapie power supply looks OK.  You might like to read the following article just to make sure.*

***How much power does the Pi4B use? Power Measurements - RasPi.TV 2019jun25***

https://raspi.tv/2019/how-much-power-does-the-pi4b-use-power-measurements

*In case you are considering UPS, here are some references:*

***Raspi UPS HAT Board***

http://www.raspberrypiwiki.com/index.php/Raspi_UPS_HAT_Board

http://www.raspberrypiwiki.com/images/6/6f/How-to-use-via-i2c.pdf

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n2amD_gU4A4

*Of course you can consider the official power supply.  But they are much more expensive：*

***Testing Official Rpi4 PSU***

https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=243942

*I don't like wall warts, so I am using this desktop version:*

***XiaoMi CDQ06ZM PD 60W 6-Port USB-C Desktop Charger (18W PD Port x 1, 18W QC Port x 1 and 2.4A Ports x 4)***

[https://www.amazon.com/Chargers-Xiaomi-Charging-Charger-Universal/dp/B07MDRFM3Q](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07MDRFM3Q)

https://uae.digshop.com/products/xiaomi-power-delivery-60w-6-port-usb-c-desktop-charger/

*And this discussion is good.*

***Choosing a Pi4 power supply - 2019jun***

[Choosing a Pi4 power supply](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/99983/choosing-a-pi4-power-supply)

*I don't know how power hungry is you NAS drive.  You might like to read my answer to the followng question to get a rough idea of the problems with HDD and SSD.*

***Can the 3b+ power two usb SSD drives?***

[Can the 3b+ power two usb SSD drives?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/100353/can-the-3b-power-two-usb-ssd-drives/100357#100357)

*Actually QC3.0 Charger is usually OK for Rpi4B.*

***Can I power 2 raspberry pi 3 B+ using a USB hub?***

[can i power 2 raspberry pi 3 B+ using a USB hub?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/99075/can-i-power-2-raspberry-pi-3-b-using-a-usb-hub)

.END